# Autocomplete Class methods in textmate?

Tags: ruby, textmate

When I define a class "Bla" with the method "foo" in a file and than create a new file and write in textmate "Bla.f" is there a way to autocomplete the missing "oo"?

I only found the ESC key but it doesn't work for this.

Answer (score 4):

TextMate autocomplete only works with words you have already typed out in the same file. If you really need this functionality, I would check out some other editors. My personal favorite is VIM. In a way, it gives you the best of both worlds. It's very lightweight and has autocomplete across files. This means if you have a class *Bla* open in one tab, you can do autocomplete with it elsewhere in your application. If you're really looking for true class autocompletion, you'll need a full IDE like NetBeans or RubyMine.

Comment: +1 for vim also. I've used it for years on Macs, Windows, and various *nix flavors. I just compile, or load, a vim with my language choices and graphical mode, and I've got the same behavior. Few other editors can claim that. I also use TextMate, Coda and BBEdit on my Macs for some features they do more conveniently, but I could do it all with vim, and use vim exclusively on Linux.