# Autocomplete already defined variables in TextMate

Tags: textmate

Taking a tutorial on basic programming. I'm using TextMate as the text editor and can't seem to get it to pull in previously defined variables when using them later in the file.

For example, if I write:

var str = "Hello" + "World";

and then write:

alert(st

I noticed in the tutorial, the teachers editor completes it with str. I've been looking all over to see if TextMate supports this functionality, but can't seem to find it. Is this possible or do I need another editor?

This answer seems to imply that it should complete if using terms used in the same file:

[Autocomplete Class methods in textmate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609679/autocomplete-class-methods-in-textmate)

But it doesn't happen that way when I'm writing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the escape key to autocomplete.